# Prove this Matrix series converges

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $A\epsilon L(\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n) $ and $ \left \| A \right \|_{op}<1$.

Prove that the series $Id-A+A^2-A^3+A^4-....$ converges in $L(\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n)$.

So I understand that $A^n\rightarrow 0$ as n approaches $\infty$ but I don't see how I prove it using $ \left \| A \right \|_{op}<1$.

Comment: Instead of using $\backslash epsilon$ $(\epsilon)$ to denote that $A$ a $n \times n$-matrix, use $\backslash in$ ($\in$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the properties of matrix norms to show that
$$
\|I - A + A^2 - A^3 + \cdots\| \leq 
\|I\| + \|A\| + \|A\|^2 + \|A\|^3 + \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use this fact: Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be normed space, suppose $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n$ converges in $X$ then  $\|x_n\|\to 0$ (to prove it use Cauchy condition)